# Send byte array (no file) from Android to PHP script?

Tags: php, android, arrays, http, byte

I would like to send a byte array with Android (loopj Async HTTP Client) to a webserver. The webserver should receive a byte array. Unfortunately when I try to output the data the output is empty. It works with strings, but not with a byte array. I used the code from the developer website to send the data.

On client side:

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("field", byteArrayData);
```

On server side:

```
$array = $_POST["field"];
echo $array;
```

Can you help me to handle a byte array as input on the server side? Should I use $_REQUEST or something else than $_POST?

Comment: encode it to base 64 and send it

Comment: If you want to `POST` your file in this manner, like abbiya said, encode your file to base64 then decode it in php and save it as you want.

Comment: I know that this is possible. But is there a possibility without encoding? Might the encoding cause problems with large byte arrays?

Comment: if you use a special type of custom Http client configuration you could receive the file in PHP with `$_FILES` and then use php function `http://php.net/move_uploaded_file` to move to a directory on your server. There are a few clients that allow for file uploads as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should upload the bytes as a file, then in php you can save the input data.

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/my.bin', file_get_contents('php://input'));
```